# Пропали картинки с сайта при использовании чпу в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Доброго всем вечера, ночи господа

После включения htaccess на сайте пропали абсолютно все картинки, ссылки на js и css. Может ли кто подсказать, как и настройки сохранить, для изменения урл, и что бы ссылки на файлы работали?

```
// причита всех безобразий
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?my=$1 [L,QSA]
```

p.s. пробовал даже абсолютные пути к файлам прописывать, и даже добавлять в head сайта

```
<base href="адрес где лежит htaccess">
```

не помогло

Comment: Указывайте абсолютный путь к файлам и графическим изображениям и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Уважаемый, так и пишу (в теме написал), не помогло. Может есть какие то альтернативные методы?

Comment: Если переходить непосредственно по урлу картинки, что выдаёт?

Comment: Картинку. Решение от @SilverIce помогло

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`, а не  `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}`
!!!

Comment: Действительно в этом дело было. Спасибо